# Multiple webcams per browser page

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webcam, getusermedia

We have a laptop with one built-in webcam and 2 external USB webcams. I would like to receive images from all three webcams at the same time. I know that since 2018 this is possible.
I am using the following code to work with one camera, but how to display the image from three cameras at once?

```js
<script>
var video = null;
var canvas = null;
var canvasContext = null;
var webimage = null;
var statusLabel = null;

function initVideo() {
    video = document.getElementById("monitor");
    statusLabel = document.getElementById("LBLSTATUS");
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
}

function setStatus(aStatus) {
    statusLabel.innerHTML = aStatus;
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    video.onerror = function () {
        stream.stop();
        streamError();
    };
                video.srcObject = stream;
    //video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);  -> Deprecated 
}

function noStream() {
    setStatus('No camera available.');
}
 
function streamError() {
    setStatus('Camera error.');
}

 </script>
```

Comment: Set up each camera such that it streams at a specific port, then add three iframes, each with the ip and port of the corresponding camera.

Comment: These are not IP cameras, they do not transmit any streams, these are ordinary USB webcams, just need to display their image in the user's browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all 3 cameras deviceIDs. Once you get those, make 3 calls to getUserMedia, each with the respective camera ids.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {
    deviceId:{
      exact: videoSource
    },
  },
}).then(function( video ) {
  const localVidElem = document.getElementById( 'localVideo1' );
  localVidElem.srcObject = video;
})
```

```
<video id="localVideo1"></video>
```

Make sure that you have the correct DeviceID and then assign it a srcObject. For more info about that, please read the [official WebRTC docs](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/media-devices#local_playback).